# How to make Selenium refresh page to last state of its elements?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python + Selenium script that helps me scrape information. However, the webpage encounters an error from time to time and then I need to refresh the page and scrape again. The problem is that the error is erratic and it might crash my scraper when I already clicked some buttons or filled some forms.

I need to find an elegant method to refresh the page exactly with the same buttons clicked (I mean, exactly to the same state). Any help?

Comment: i don't think it's possible in selenium. the only way is to record each event and reply again. not a good solution but only option, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

if you build a robust scrapy system,you must think about exception handling . i have done some large scrape project .in these projects we will use a log system to record the  exception ,then retry when don't success scraping the message.

Comment: Ok, but how do you retry? I need to change the user agent and refresh the page by resubmitting the form. Seems like Selenium doesn't integrate this so easily. OR, repeat the same `for` loop iteration (on which I am working on right now).

Comment: you can choose a global varible to record the exception time. then use try except to do retry

Comment: Thank you for help. I think the problem is "how to retry", because I can surely detect when the exception occurred.